# CakePHP 3 Pb with saving data into BD

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I have a table ComplexesEmployeesImmeubles :

```
id auto-increment
complex_id foreign key of Complexes.ID
employee_id foreign key of Employees.ID
immeuble_id foreign key of Immeubles.ID
poste_id foreign key of Postes.ID
date_affectation 
created
```

here is my view reaffecter.ctp

```
<?= $this->Form->create('ComplexesEmployeesImmeubles') ?>
<?php

echo $this->Form->select('complex_id', $complexes);
echo $this->Form->input('employee_id',['type' => 'hidden' , 'value' => h($employee->id)]);

echo $this->Form->select('immeuble_id', $immeubles);

echo $this->Form->select('poste_id', $postes);
echo $this->Form->input('salaire', ['label' => 'Salaire']);
echo $this->Form->input('date_affectation', ['label' => 'Date d\'affectation']);
?>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

In my controller, I try to save data into my BD with the code below but nothing is saved !

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
$complexesEmployeesImmeuble = $this->ComplexesEmployeesImmeubles->newEntity();
$complexesEmployeesImmeuble = $this->ComplexesEmployeesImmeubles->patchEntity($complexesEmployeesImmeuble, $this->request->data);
 $this->ComplexesEmployeesImmeubles->save($complexesEmployeesImmeuble);}
```

Comment: "_Pb_", "_BD_"? Please don't use such crude abbreviations, they are hard to understand, and even harder to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `debug($complexesEmployeesImmeuble->errors())` to check whether validation failed.

```
if(!$this->ComplexesEmployeesImmeubles->save($complexesEmployeesImmeuble)){
  debug($complexesEmployeesImmeuble->errors()); die;
 }
```

If you didn't get errors and still not saved then check for mass assignment , more info http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#mass-assignment

Comment: thanks for your help, using $complexesEmployeesImmeuble->errors() helped me to
define the problem. I had removed a field from my table but I didn't update the model 
where the field is defined as 'required' !